# Receipt template $line.description not showing

Tags: civicontribute, receipts, invoice, line-items, printing

Hoping for some assistance for some issues with the invoice and receipt for the online contributions.

Even though the script for the line item description is present in the template (below), no description is printing in HTML, text, or PDF format of the receipts.

In this case the main concern is charitable items that include the charity number in the description. I haven't worked much with the mail templates but nothing glaringly wrong is jumping out at me.

This is from "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)". I can post the whole thing if needed.

Also, on the invoice the below script for the Description is pulling something completely different from what I input at Administer > CiviContribute > Financial Accounts. That's the only place I've been able to find to set the description. I can't seem to find where the text that is showing has been input anywhere. If someone can give me a hint here it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any assistance,
Pennopoly

```
The following has had HTML stripped out

  {if $lineItem and $priceSetID and !$is_quick_config}

   {foreach from=$lineItem item=value key=priceset}

       {foreach from=$value item=line}

         {if $line.html_type eq 'Text'}{$line.label}{else}{$line.field_title} - {$line.label}{/if} 
              {if $line.description}
                  <div>{$line.description|truncate:30:"..."}
                  </div>
              {/if}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your receipt, and include what you would like for it to say? It might help bring clarity to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The description field that is rendered in the receipt is part of an option value that is used in a field in of a price set (See screenshot). But I wonder if that is useful for your what you want to do?
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kainuk - CiviCooP, I see that for the select options but the field in question is a Text field so I don't have an "Edit Price Option" link for that.